# Git force revert to HEAD~7

Tags: git

I committed and pushed some bad things. How do I force revert my local repo to HEAD~7, and re-commit so that HEAD is now at that version? Git docs confuse me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The nicest approach is to push another commit that reverts the unintended commits. See [Jakub Narębski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/revert-multiple-git-commits/1470452#1470452) on how to do that.

If for some reason it's worth the potential unfriendliness of pushing an update that isn't a fast-forward (sensitive bits in the commits, for example), give these commands:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~7
git push --force origin master
```

The first rewinds your current branch. This is a sharp tool, so be careful.

To stop you accidentally losing work, git won't push your rewound branch. The `--force` option disables this safety feature.

Answer (score 7):

`git reset --hard HEAD~7` will discard your changes entirely.

`git reset HEAD~7` will drop the commits but leave changes in the working copy, so that you can edit and re-commit them.