# SVN: possible to remove commits on the central repo?

Tags: svn

In git, reset seems to remove commits from history, and pushing that change to remote removes history of certain commits from not only the local master but origin (remote) master.

Essentially: [Resetting remote to a certain commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816688/reseting-remote-to-a-certain-commit)

Is this possible in SVN?

Ie. Not looking to create a reverse merge in svn (aka revert in git), but literally erase history from the central repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not currently supported in SVN.  From [the FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal):

> The project has plans, however, to someday implement an `svnadmin obliterate` command which would accomplish the task of permanently deleting information. (See [issue 516](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=516).)

However, there is a workaround that can work in some cases:

> In the meantime, your only recourse is to `svnadmin dump` your repository, then pipe the dumpfile through `svndumpfilter` (excluding the bad path) into an `svnadmin load` command. See [chapter 5 of the Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin) for details about this.

The filter mechanism works at the file path level, including or excluding parts of the repository as a whole across all revisions.  This is often insufficient if you want to omit a particular revision of a file, or you've committed files to a filtered path before or after the offending revision that you want to keep.