# Reset pushed changes git repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I had accidentally committed and pushed modifications to some files to a branch on bitbucket. When I wanted to remove these files from the commit I used the rm command and ended up deleting the files. What I am trying to say is, I ended up deleting the files instead of removing the modifications on them. I tried using git reset but that only resets my latest commit, while the wrong commit/push was several points backwards. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resetting remote to a certain commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816688/resetting-remote-to-a-certain-commit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Undo pushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits)

Answer (score -1):

You need to execute following commands:

(if there are no changes, that were submitted after your push)
1. Reset your changes:
git reset --hard 
2. Update origin:
git push origin  -f (it will force push your changes).

Comment: Force push is usually not what you want.

Comment: It depends on the situation if he needs to fix files in his own branch (why not).