# Git create revert to a specific commit

Tags: git, github

I'm sorry for another git post but I've searched a lot and tried everything I saw before this post.

I changed to master from a "dirty" branch without noticing and all the commits merged to master and more.

I want to create a revert commit from a certain commit hash in the past.

For example, my head is 100 commits ahead from commit 'abcdef'.
I want from my current head to create a revert which will make my new head same as it was after commit 'abcdef'.

Eventually all needs to be pushed to remote repository (bitbucket)

I used git-reset but it just brings me to the desired point in time, without the revert-commit. Is there a way to force a push of all files. I tried using 'git add -f filename' but when I do git status it is not there as there are no changes from the current head which is 'abcdef'

Tried:
[How to revert multiple git commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/how-to-revert-multiple-git-commits)

[Resetting remote to a certain commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816688/resetting-remote-to-a-certain-commit)

Comment: Do you really want to revert? This will create additional commits that "undo" the incorrect ones. Or do you just want to reset branch `abcdef` back to its original state which will completely remove all of the commits.

Comment: What do you mean by "dirty branch"? Did you have local changes which were not yet commited? Did you commit these changes directly to master? It will help if you provide the exact commands you performed that got you to the current state.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, i want to create one additional commit which revert all other 100

Comment: @GalZiv if you really want "one single commit" to revert all, you need to use `git revert --no-commit`, otherwise git will make one revert commit for each commit until that you pass as argument

Comment: @JohnnyWiller yup this is what I used. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you want is `git reset --hard <commit>`. This will reset the current branch to some other commit. If you have already pushed the branch to bitbucket, you will need to do `git push -f` to force push.

**Beware**

This will cause problems for other team members who are working on the same branch. Only do this if you are the only person working on the branch.

Comment: @GalZiv Already tried what? You need to provide more details in order for anyone here to be able to help you.

Comment: git reset --hard <commit>

Comment: I eventually used git revert head~1 --no-commit until i got to where i wanted