# New commits are rejected since I removed the last commit

Tags: git

I made an unintended commit and pushed to the remote. But then I wanted to undo it. So I executed:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

> HEAD is now at b760747 random commit

Then I made some changes and attempted to add+commit+push it. But it failed with the following error message:

> ! [rejected]        postacl -> postacl (non-fast-forward) error:
>   failed to push some refs to (repository-url)

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How can I get everything back to normal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resetting remote to a certain commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816688/resetting-remote-to-a-certain-commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do force push to remote server. That way it would fix your problem. You can do it by the following command.

```
git push -f origin branch_name
```

But be careful, because this would overwrite the git history. You can read about the problems in [this article](https://blog.sensible.io/2012/10/09/git-to-force-put-or-not-to-force-push.html)

Comment: Is that a problem if git history is overwritten?

Comment: I have attached an article. Kindly go through it and also consult your other team members before you do `git push --force`

Comment: You should also be aware that it is now preferable to use '--force-with-lease' that bring a little more security by preventing the lost of other developers commits that you didn't see/fetched.

Answer (score 0):

*( Disclaimer : if you're alone on your repo, go for argo's quick and efficient method! )*

I'd like to add the alternative to the forced push method which could, in some contexts, be a big no-no (namely, **if you're not alone on the repo then people could (and will!) have history conflicts** with your rewritten master on the repo).

It's no big secret but let's add it for completion :

```
# make sure you're on the right branch (here I assume it's "master")
git checkout master
# let's get upo-to-date with the (now wrong) remote master
git pull
# alternatively to this pull, you could have undone your reset with reflog
# be free to use the one you're more familiar with

# locate the "bad" commit and store its hash for further use
# (I'll do a log but you could have prefered methods.)
git log --oneline

# create a commit which has the exact opposite modifications of <bad> commit.
git revert <bad>
# (no need to commit the previous action since the commit is already created)

# push the new commit on top of remote master (I assume "origin" for your remote)
git push origin master
```

I'll grant you it seems slightly clunkier and adds noise to the history, BUT you didn't rewrite history and your co-users will hate you less. Hurray!