# merge deletes folders because of commit's history

Tags: git, merge, pull

I have 4 branches on my repository:
`project1`,
`project2`,
`project3`
& `gh-pages`

All `project` branches merged into the `gh-pages` and have their own folder there

After I merged `project3` into the `gh-pages` I did some changes to **project3 files** **being on `gh-pages`** branch.

After that I returned on my `project3`, made few changes & push to `project3` remote.
When i wanted to merge `project3` into the `gh-pages` i've got conflict, resolve it, but after this somehow `gh-pages` merged into `project3` and now I have all folders (project1, project, project3) on my `project3` branch. I did *fetch, pull and delete* this folders from my local `project3`, commit this changes to my remote `project3` and now if I merge `project3` to `gh-pages` this is going to delete project1 and project2 folders on `gh-pages`

What should i do?

Comment: This is not helpful to you, but to me your setup looks like something I have never seen. Why is it important that each branch only contains one of those projects?

Comment: I would recommend not using branches as a means of managing different projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `git reset --hard 123abc` your `project3` branch to the commit before the accidental merge, and `git push -f`.

Be careful to check the state you are pushing to not lose anything!

This answer is more extensive: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816761/3280244