# How to roll back a Pull Request in AWS Code commit

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, github, aws-codecommit

I'm looking for an option to revert a merged `Pull Request` in `AWS code commit` **with out involving `cli`** similar to the revert option in `Github`.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** :- I know this could be achieved through `cli`. But that is not what I need. How this can be achieved using `code commit` interface, is the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resetting remote to a certain commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816688/resetting-remote-to-a-certain-commit)

Comment: This is related to git not code commit

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I have mentioned in the question that I need to achieve it not but using `cli`. Also, I'm specifically looking for this to be done in code commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using the management console.

Comment: Did you mean "You can't do this **without** using the console."?

Comment: @Prolog No. AFAIK, AWS refers to to it as the [mangement console](https://aws.amazon.com/console/). I edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: @Rich what changes to the answer would you recommend? what the OP is asking for is not possible.