GIT-Extensions: how to set "origin" branch on a previous value?
I have a "dev" branch, local as well as remote (origin), and I would like to set the remote branch on a previous commit:
Current situation (GIT-extensions screenshot):

I would like the "origin/dev" remote branch to refer to the entry below, while keeping the local "dev" branch on the same spot.
How can I do this?
For your information: I already tried "reset current branch to here", but that keeps the "origin/dev" and moves the "dev" (the local one), but I want just the opposite.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816761/7976758 After reset you should force-push. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+move+remote+branch

origin/dev reflects state of dev branch in the remote origin repository.
So you can only move origin/dev by updating the remote branch which is done by pushing.
If your state has still not changed and the image still reflect your current branch state, you could update it by pushing either HEAD~ or equivalent in this case dev~ (i.e. the parent commit of HEAD or dev commit. You can also use the hash of the commit but it's less convenient).
It will looks like that when pushing:

Note: "Force with lease" (or "Force push") are mandatory because you want to "remove" a commit from the existing remote branch.

A Git GUI client is a tool that all developers should use to understand the history of a branch and its relationship with the other branches. However, some Git operations are difficult to perform using a GUI client, or even impossible. Knowing the Git commands (and understanding their effects) is mandatory.
Having these said, while the action that you ask is probably possible using a Git GUI, the easiest way to accomplish it remains the command line:
$ git push --force-with-lease origin dev~1:dev

This command pushes updates the remote branch dev on remote origin to point to the first parent commit (~1) of the commit pointed by the local dev branch (dev~1).
This is a destructive operation (the remote repository will "forget" the commit that is currently pointed by the dev branch) and Git refuses to do it. The options --force and --force-with-lease tell Git "Please continue, I know what I'm doing".
While --force blindly executes the operation, the option --force-with-lease uses a safety net. If another developer has pushed more commits on origin/dev since your last git fetch, you don't know that these commits exist. If you use --force, Git removes them but if you use --force-with-lease, Git refuses to perform the operation, preventing you to delete somebody else's work without even knowing.
After you run git fetch again (and your local repository "knows" about the commits that you are about to delete), running git push --force-with-lease again succeeds (because now you really know what you're doing.)
Always use --force-with-lease if your git push changes the branch history!
