# Git: move HEAD back to a previous commit

Tags: git

I've made some changes in my master branch that I no longer see fit. For arguments sake, I have a commit hash named `791fda4e1ac0e1a393e01340bf0fba3f333a73ff` that I'd like to make my HEAD now, as that's when everything was stable in the repo. I've tried to do the following:

```
git reset 791fda4e1ac 
git reset --soft HEAD@{1} 
git commit -m "Revert to 791fda4e1ac"
git reset --hard
```

Yet, when I do a `git push origin`, I get rejected, because origin thinks it's a non-fastforward push:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

What's the right way of reverting my HEAD back to commit hash 791fda4e1ac and getting the origin server there as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's rejected because it *is* non-fast-forward — it discards history others may have built on.

Use `git revert` instead to create a new commit which undoes the effect of the existing ones.

Or, if you're sure no one else is using your repository and you don't care about those commits in the future, go ahead and `git push -f` to ignore the warning.

Comment: @drevicko See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/revert-multiple-git-commits for various possibilities. I like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/revert-multiple-git-commits#comment19940208_11743042 best.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a forced push (`git push -f origin`).