# How to specify each past commit when reverting several into a new commit

Tags: git

My last three commits are the following:

```
commit 440badcebc459fd6e0aec6df3acd68bbfe797f14
Author: Michael J <michael@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 12 02:27:20 2013 +0200

    Add config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

commit 4ca67cdeeab3290bc3fb3349d6c1b606ed61d5f8
Author: Michael J <michael@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 12 02:22:04 2013 +0200

    Added a bogus file to shared.

commit 0dd36b5705598ccb7878c5eee9e09f8e1a75296e
Author: Michael J <michael@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 12 02:17:24 2013 +0200

    Change js structure.
```

I want to revert those three commits with the method mentioned in [a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470452/1417223), i.e. by

> "... create a new commit which reverts changes that you want to get rid of ..."

[The docs gives an example on how this could look like](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html):

```
git revert -n master~5..master~2
```

I'm unsure though what to put as an argument: `master-something`, `HEAD-something`, the commit message or the commit id?

**What should I put as a an argument after -n/--no-commit given the the example commits above?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will revert the changes done by commits from the 3rd last commit in master (included) to the 1st last commit in master (included):

```
git revert -n master~3..master
```

Comment: This is probably the best way, at least if you're on `master` (using `HEAD~3..HEAD` would be branch-agnostic), but since you already have the commit SHA1s from the `git log output`, you could also `git revert -n 0dd36b..440bad`