# In git, how do you revert a file back to 3 commits ago?

Tags: git, git-revert

I changed an image file in git and it was 2 commits ago. How do I go back to 2 previous commits ago?

What is the easiest method of doing this file revert via the command line with the least amount of commands required?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert multiple git commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/revert-multiple-git-commits)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just check out the old version of that file:

```
git checkout HEAD~2 -- path/to/file
```

Or more explicit:

```
git checkout commit-id -- path/to/file
```

Comment: what does HEAD~2 mean ?

Comment: `HEAD` is the currently checked out commit, and `HEAD~n` is *nth* commit before that. So it’s the version two commits ago. The `--` is used to tell Git to treat the remaining argument as a file path.

Comment: wha thappens if i left out the -- :  git checkout <commit-id> path/to/file

Comment: It will likely work, but in case the path is something that Git might be able to interpret as command parameters, you will get an error. So the safe route is to simply include that `--`.