# Git - move the last commit of another branch on top of the main branch

Tags: git, merge

All the related questions ask about moving commits from the main branch to another branch.

My problem is somehow opposite:

```
M(n)-M(n+1)-M(n+2)-M(n+3)
\
B(1)-B(2)-B(3)-B(4)-B(5)
```

Consider that `M` stands for a commit on master and `B` for a commit on a secondary branch.
The contents of the parantheses are indexes.

I want to merge the branches and move `B(5)` on top of the main branch, so right after `M(n+3)`, disregarding any change made from `M(n)` to `M(n+3)`.

I'm avoiding to use `git rebase`, as the structure of my repo is the same as that of a shared repo, and I don't know what will happen if I would rewrite the history with `git rebase` in this context.

Comment: I'm not sure how you actually _do_ this with commands, but it sounds like what you want is to _relabel_ the branches, so that B is now master and M is discarded, and I know that that's _possible_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sequence of git commands:

```
 git checkout M
 git reset --hard HEAD~3
 git merge B
```

Answer (score 0):

If your commits are pushed to a remote repository, you can't just move things around.  If the commits on branch M are only local then you can rollback to M(n) and merge branch B to it which will get you what you want.

However, if the commits have been pushed you should avoid this because you have rewritten history and will have to do a `git push -f`.  If anyone else has pulled the changes then it will cause a lot of problems.  In this case you will need to revert the changes from M(n+1) to M(n+3).

Using this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470452/498699

```
git revert --no-commit M(n+3)
git revert --no-commit M(n+2)
git revert --no-commit M(n+1)
git commit
```

Now you can merge branch B and have the changes applied correctly and anyone else that has pulled the changes will not have any difficulties pulling your changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have B(5) (and none of B(1) to B(4)) right after M(n+3)
then you can just run

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick B(5)
```

If you want all of B(1) to B(5) after M(n+3) but do not want to change the history of B, no worry, just create a new C branch.

```
git checkout -b C_branch B_branch
git rebase --onto master `git merge-base C_branch master` C_branch
```

That will give

```
M(n)-M(n+1)-M(n+2)-M(n+3)
\                        \
B(1)-B(2)-B(3)-B(4)-B(5)  C(1)-C(2)-C(3)-C(4)-C(5)
```