# git sound like deleting my commits after checkout previous ons

Tags: git

I have 7 commits in my git and i checkout the 5th commit and then I created a branch from it.
after that the 6th commit and the 7th commit disappeared?
I checked both branches the master and the new one by using gui git apps and by git log and I find nothing about me 6th and 7th commits.

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question to include more details. What commands did you run? What did your commit tree look like before and after? Where did you expect these commits to show up?

Comment: sounds ike you must have been committing not to `master` but to a `detached HEAD`. you can just run `git reflog` to find the missing commits, then `checkout` a live branch and `cherry-pick` said commits onto it. or you can search and probably there are plenty of scenarios similar to whatever yours is, although it's rather vague right now.

Comment: can you share the output of `git log --oneline --graph --all` this can me understand the structure of yours commits.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have 7 commits, and you are branching out at 5th, so your branch won't have further commits. Take a look at commits history (suppose branch is named `new_branch` and you branched out from `master`):

```
    new_branch
      ↓
C4 <- C5 <- C6 <- C7
                  ↑
                master
```

`new_branch` points to fifth commit and cannot see it's descendant. Try using `git log master`, it will show history of `master` branch.

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841671/reverting-to-a-specific-commit-without-losing-history) for reference.