# Git revert several commits

Tags: git, git-reset, git-revert

I have made several commits to my local branch `estimation` and pushed them to the remote branch `estimation`.

Now, I want to remove the last 3 commits completely.

I tried to do `git reset HEAD^` and `git reset HEAD --hard` 3 times but when I tried to push the changes, it complained about tip of the HEAD not aligned.

How do I do it?

**EDIT:**

The history looks like following:

`commit e572aab4e18`

`commit e21e7310bc4`

`commit 4f372a513da`

`commit 31a4ac607ae`

`commit a1a6e3f02dd`

I would like to remove top 4 and go back to `commit a1a6e3f02dd` and make both local and remote branch on same HEAD.

Comment: you can look for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1470452/1475228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: **You should only do this for a branch that you're not sharing**; if the branch is checked out by others, this process will put their local copies out of sync with the remote and they won't be able to just push commits to the branch anymore. This can be sorted out but it's potentially a mess.

Given that, if I understand you correctly, you're in this situation:

```
xxxxxxx Bad commit #3
yyyyyyy Bad commit #2
zzzzzzz Bad commit #3
wwwwwww This and everything before it are fine
```

You want to drop the commits after `wwwwwwww` and fix the remote branch to match.

First, back up the branch you're doing surgery on so you can restore it if you mess up, and then switch back to the branch you want to remove commits from.

```
git checkout -b broken-estimation
git checkout estimation
```

Run `git log` to find the SHA1 of the first commit you want to keep. Once you have that SHA1, reset the branch to that:

```
git reset --hard kkkkkkk
```

where `kkkkkk` is the SHA1 of the first commit you want to keep on the branch.

Run `git log` again to ensure you've got the desired SHA1 as the tip of this branch; it should be the first commit you see in the `git log` output. If you've not trimmed off enough commits, redo the `git reset --hard` with the proper SHA1 to remove more commits.

If you removed *too many* commits, restore the `estimation` branch from the backup you took:

```
git checkout -B estimation broken-estimation
```

and redo the `git log` to find the SHA1 of the commit you want at the tip, followed by `git reset --hard kkkkkkk` (with `kkkkkkk` being the SHA1 you actually wanted) to drop the undesired commits following that commit.

Once you've got the branch in the desired state, you can push the fixed branch to the remote, replacing the old version:

```
git push -f the_proper_remote estimation
```

Once you're certain that your repairs are correct, you can delete the backup copy of the branch:

```
git branch -d broken-estimation
```

Answer (score 5):

If you already pushed the commits (and don't want to do a force-push and overwrite data in the remote repository, there are a couple things you can do):

You can use `git revert` instead of `git reset`:

```
$ git revert ~4..HEAD
```

Or you can use `git checkout` and then commit the changes:

```
$ git checkout ~3 -- .
$ git commit
```

`git revert` will do 3 separate revert commits. The `git checkout` method will allow you to revert the changes in just one single commit.

In your case, you could do this:

```
$ git reset --hard $REMOTE/$BRANCH
$ git checkout a1a6e3f02dd -- .
$ git commit
```

Comment: Thanks Mipadi. I am little confused so I have provided more information. Can you please have a look at it

Comment: @chintans: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks but now my branch is `a1a6e3f02dd` but I want to just remove all the 4 commits completely so my local remote brach both point `a1a6e3f02dd`.

Comment: @chintans: Since you already did a reset locally, you'll have to reset instead to the HEAD of your remote branch, then do `git checkout` and `git commit`. Answer updated.

Comment: He wants to rewrite history through force-push.  He doesn't want to add 4 new "revert" commits on top of his existing history.  p.s. I recommend squashing a sequence of reverts into a single commit with "git rebase -i".

Comment: @G.SylvieDavies: Where does he say he wants to do a forced push? That's not really a _great_ idea for a repo that other people have access to (although it's one solution).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in three commands:

First, rewrite the history of the remote branch:

```
git push origin +a1a6e3f02dd:estimation
```

Note, the "+" causes it to be a "force-push".  This command says "force a1a6e3f02dd to be the tip of the origin/estimation branch."

Once that's done, you just need to get your local "estimation" branch synchronized with the remote one:

```
git checkout estimation
get reset --hard origin/estimation
```

And you're done!  But be forewarned:  'git reset --hard' will blast away any uncommitted work you have in that project.

If others are also working with the 'estimation' branch, and they have already pulled your 4 "bad" commits into their branches, then there is going to be a bit of a coordination mess.  But in my experience all the warnings and admonishments about "never rewrite history of shared branches" is overblown.  It should be restated:  never rewrite history of **long-lived** shared branches.