# How do I revert multiple commits in Git Kraken?

Tags: git, git-revert, git-gui, gitkraken

I know you can revert a single commit and right-clicking the commit and clicking revert. But is there a way to revert multiple commits (like the latest five commits on a single branch)?.

Comment: If you can't find a way to do this with Kraken, have a look at something like [this](http://serebrov.github.io/html/2014-01-04-git-revert-multiple-recent-comments.html) to do it directly from the Git bash.

Comment: From the latest to the oldest revert them one by one. If you can revert the last one, then you can revert the rest four.

Comment: @ElpieKay It can get tedious when there are several commits to revert.

Answer (score 14):

you could revert back to the commit you want and force-push it, but that would destroy some of your history, which is what you usually want to avoid while working in GIT

There's another **much better** way to do it in GitKraken:
let's say this is your commit history
`A - B - C - D` (D being the latest commit)
now you want to revert B,C&D

1. reset hard to `A` (make sure you stash any open changes before doing that)
2. reset soft to `D` (yes, resetting to a later commit is actually possible)
3. write your commit message and commit

now your history should look like this
`A - B - C - D - A'` (`A'` having the same content as `A`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more popular question with a good answer on how to solve this with git. You can derive from it how to do it in GitKraken.
[How to revert multiple git commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/how-to-revert-multiple-git-commits)