# Tortoise Git - 'Reset "master" to this' doesn't do the job

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-revert

I am trying to rewind my repository a few commits back.

After opening the commit log, I choose the commit that I want to rewind to, then `Reset "master" to this...`, then `Hard: Reset working tree and index`.

When opening the logs again, all later commits are indeed gone.

But when I pull the repository from clean, they're back in there.

This task used to be simple with Subversion (although, not entirely deleting a bunch of commits, just reverting to a previous commit, which doesn't show in Tortoise Git menu unless you choose THE previous commit, i.e., one before most recent).

Any idea how to achieve my goal?

Comment: ...all later commits are indeed gone. Then you should do a `git push -f` to **rewrite** the remote, or we say, "sync" this edit.

Comment: @GenoChen: Thank you, but I tried that; Got an error message saying I need to pull first because I'm not pointing to latest. Then, after pulling, everything is back to where it was.

Comment: Did you add the `-f` or `--force` parameter?

Comment: @GenoChen: Doing it via Tortoise, so don't recall seeing such option, but will try again; one sec please...

Comment: Then I wonder if there is a checkbox saying something like "Force push" when you are preparing for a push...

Comment: @GenoChen: Yes!!! Well, similar. There's a title `Force` with two check-boxes - `known changes` and `unknown changes`. When I marked the first, the second was disabled. And `push` completed successfully this time! After pulling from clean, all later commits are gone. Thank you!!!

Comment: If you want to revert via command line, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/how-to-revert-multiple-git-commits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The menu `Reset "master"` just means "Reset local master", not a **remote** master.

That is, no remote operation is occured when you click this option. This is a basic difference between Git and SVN: Git does many local operations, just do remote operation when needed, but all operation in SVN are remote required.

To update, or we say *sync* the modification of your resetting, just do a `git push -f` to force rewrite the remote.

**Warning:** Check twice, make sure you are clear what you are doing before executing `git push -f`, or you may lost your necessary work.

Answer (score 0):

To force remote update is a risky operation and may be even not allowed.
E.g. I’ve received on GitHub

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.
remote: error: Cannot force-push to this protected branch
```

The better suggestion from  https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/2817#issuecomment-432715832 :

1. Create a new branch,
 2. commit your code to the branch
 3. and do a pull request.
 4. Someone will have to approve it depending on repo settings.