# HEAD detached at a sha1

Tags: git, github

I have a branch(mybranch) with 6 commits. After 6 commits I want to revert the last   3 commits. So I checked out sha using `git checkout 3978bf85d8a05653c927cfabdf8c018167faf363` I can see last 3 commits are reverted. Now I want to update mybranch with this. How can I do that?

```
(hase) root@ajain1:~/hase# git status
HEAD detached at 3978bf8
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: `HEAD` is just a pointer, not a real branch. You haven't reverted anything; you've just pointed at something that isn't a branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to 'force' a particular branch to point to a specific commit/ID, you can simply do:

```
git checkout mybranch
git reset --hard 3978bf8
```

And it will update `mybranch` to point directly to that commit.

Comment: It did, but unable to push ` ! [rejected]        mybranch -> mybranch (non-fast-forward)`

Comment: Are you trying to push to a repository that _other people_ have access to? If so, you should probably reconsider what you're doing - a "force push" is rarely recommended when used against a public repository. If this is a private repository/fork that only you access, you can force the push using: `git push -f <remote>`

Answer (score 1):

You might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470452/10576762) helpful which explains that new commits should be added to revert the previous commits in order to preserve the branch's history.

One way to do this is to call `$ git revert --no-commit commitHash` on the 3 commits to be reverted, and then call `$ git commit -m "the commit message"`.

An alternate solution is to checkout the contents of the last commit (let's call it A) you don't want to revert, and then commit this state which can be done with `$ git checkout -f A --` followed by `$ git commit -a`

Comment: Upvoted because this method does not destructively alter the history.

Answer (score 1):

As your HEAD is detached and currently pointing to commit 3978bf8, you can create new branch at the commit. You can merge this branch to your branch `mybranch`.

```
git branch new_branch_name
git checkout mybranch 
git merge new_branch_name
```