# git revert multiple commits and push to remote repo without having force push

Tags: git

I have to revert around 15 commits and merge the code to master, basically im trying to move head 15 commits back.
The issue is i do not have access to do a force push to remote repo.
How can we achieve this ?

i tried git revert and each time it goes one commit behind.

Comment: You can't rewrite history without force pushing. You *can* revert multiple commits, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/how-to-revert-multiple-git-commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple reverts will work only when you don't have any merge commits within your list of commits you are reverting