# How to come back to the specyfic version of code on git?

Tags: git

I've some trouble with git.
I made some mistakes with merging pull requests, and now I need to come back to specyfic version of code from chosen commit.
img -> [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjY08.png)

So. I need to back to the version of code from commit selected on img by red arrow.
How can I do this in safe way?

What I want to get from solution? I need to remove commits and everything which was made in this commits.

Comment: `git reset`....

Comment: Okay. So I need to create backup for master. On this backup run git reset [commithash] and create merge request this master backup to master?

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout <sha_of_desired_location>`

Then, if you do not want your recent commits, you can delete the branch.

`git branch -d <branch you want to delete>`

Then, the last step is to create a branch pointing to your current location

`git checkout -b <branch_name>`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to `reset` (because that would means a `git push --force`, rewriting the history of the branch), you can [revert multiple commits as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743042/6309)

```
git revert @~x..@
```

That will create a new commit which cancels intermediate commits, and that you can push.