# Use of git revert for reverting two commits

Tags: git, git-revert

I need to revert below two commits :

```
user@007:~/git/project_demo$ git log --oneline
4736674 FIXED:Included src2.cpp file in code coverage.      
d7f6712 TASK:Introduced code coverage for selected project test cases. 
60542ef TASK: Implemented first version here.
```

How can I use this `git revert` command?

Should I use git revert twice or use git revert one time and pass the absolute commit SHA1 value.

I want to come to `60542ef` commit and do the new changes on top of this commit.

Here I need to use git revert only instead of git reset.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43081965/8505949) could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep history then follow below command,

```
git revert 4736674
```

and

```
git revert d7f6712
```

then make your changes.

---

if you do not want to keep history then go down 2 commit as below

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

then perform your new changes and do

```
git push -f origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just revert them in reverse chronological order

```
git revert 4736674 
git revert d7f6712
```

If you need/want to commit both reverts as one revert commit, just add `-n` to your first revert, it'll prevent the commit and you'll get everything reverted with the second command.

And by definition with `git revert`, no need to push with force as this doesn't break history.