# How to delete commits from a folder?

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit, git-push

I have recently made commits that I want to delete, and return the folder to the state it was before the commits.

Here is an image of commit history in a folder:
[image]

How can I delete the commits made after `e1c0013`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to revert multiple git commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/how-to-revert-multiple-git-commits)

Answer (score 2):

Your screen capture indicates that 5 commits have been made on top of the `e1c0013` commit.  Assuming that you have *not* yet pushed this branch to your Git repo, you may use a hard reset:

```
# from desired branch
git reset --hard HEAD~5
```

If you *have* already pushed this branch to the remote, then you should instead *revert* the five commits:

```
# from branch "your_branch"
git revert your_branch~5..your_branch
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by pushing branch to git repo? I have a master branch and I have already used pushed the commits.

Comment: If you have already pushed your branch with the commits which you want to delete, then you should use my second suggestion of `git revert`.

Comment: So if my branch name is master then I should do git revert master~5..master?

Comment: But the commits are in a folder, how can I do that to a specific folder?

Comment: The commits are _not_ in a folder.  A Git commit is a snapshot of your entire project, including all folders in that project.

Comment: I got this error message: error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge. What should I do?

Comment: Is your working directory dirty?  If so, then you should first commit or stash your work.