# error: mainline was specified but commit is not a merge; fatal: revert failed

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-revert

I want to revert the reverted pull requests i.e. the 4 commits `6283c90`, `f665a5a`, `09ed268`, `05ed1bc`.

But when I use the command `git revert -m 1 6283c90`, I am running into the following error:

```
error: mainline was specified but commit 6283c90bd35598635fe1d4f96d3a5a8c6ed91206 is not a merge.
fatal: revert failed
```

The git log graph looks something like below:

```
* 6283c90 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) Revert "Merge pull request #1 from kgarg8/checkpoint-patch"
* f665a5a Revert "Merge pull request #2 from kgarg8/entmax-patch"
* 09ed268 Revert "Merge pull request #3 from kgarg8/decoding"
* 05ed1bc Revert "Merge pull request #4 from kgarg8/decoding"
*   2a8519e Merge pull request #4 from kgarg8/decoding
|\  
| * e170320 (origin/decoding) Fix bugs in decoding
* |   63f0f4c Merge pull request #3 from kgarg8/decoding
|\ \  
| |/  
| * f5ce256 Add temperature, top_k, top_p sampling
* |   168685e Merge pull request #2 from kgarg8/entmax-patch
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 6a44c22 (origin/entmax-patch) Add entmax support
* |   7f61831 Merge pull request #1 from kgarg8/checkpoint-patch
|\ \  
| |/  
| * ea0a7db (origin/checkpoint-patch) Checkpoint load for CPU
|/  
* 4c2d50c Update Seq2Seq_agent.py
... continues
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One will have to understand the `git revert` vs `git reset`.

**`revert`** is when you try to add another commit on top with the exact diff as inverse of the last commit(s). In your case as equivalent of a squashed (i.e. `--squash`) of all the previous 4 commits.

It's problematic to do this, when your repo is not configured as merge strategy with: `rebase + ff-only`. Based on the history you showed, the actual issue is the merge strategy used by your project.

Still, if you want to achieve a revert, you'd do ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/how-to-revert-multiple-git-commits)) :

```
$ git revert --no-commit <SHA-1 (previous)>
$ git revert --no-commit <SHA-1 (previous - 1)>
$ git revert --no-commit <SHA-1 (previous - 2)>
$ git revert --no-commit <SHA-1 (previous - 3)>
$ git commit -m "your message message"
$ git push
```

**`reset`** is to get the content to be at the SHA-1 (commit = pointer) as it was 4 commits ago. Most of the time people are looking for `revert`-ing, they actually refer to `reset`. Not sure in your case. The benefit is around governance. If you can't change history, if your user is not allowed to `push --force` (`push` with force), then you probably need to use `revert` as the governance model of your project, wants to ensure that people don't hide the mistakes, or remove (by mistake) something from history. Otherwise, `reset` is the default way to go back, especially when working on your local fork (a common example when `reset` is not allowed in teams, is for a DevOps team - for a configuration management repo).

```
$ git reset --hard <SHA-1 (previous - 3)>
$ git push --force
```

Where `<SHA-1 (previous - 3)>` is probably `05ed1bc` for you, so an actual commit SHA-1.

UPDATE: (Note) When `reset` is being used, the previous (forward) commits are not deleted, but remain orphan. They remain in the history until a `gc` (garbage collection) is being called. They remain basically in the tree (like on a different branch - but without a branch. Think of it as the TREE data structure - Computer Science). You can retrieve that commit if one wants to analyze it.

Comment: Great answer!! Didn't try out revert option. The ```reset``` option is quite interesting as it erased the 4 commits + no new commit shows up. ```revert``` would pile up 8 commits in the history instead. However, few edits I would suggest: (1) ```--hard``` instead of ```hard```, (2) Since I needed to revert the 4 commits, so instead of supplying ```05ed1bc```, I should provide one commit before this commit i.e. ```2a8519e```, o/w it resets only 3 commits.

Comment: Fixed the `--hard` parameter. Sure, now that you know how it works, feel free to play with the right SHA you need. One thing I forget to remind is that the commits are not erased, but they are orphaned, until garbage collection is being used. I need to provide that as an update. Thanks for reminder!