# Git Revert Back to Previous Before Commit

Tags: git, github

I am trying to view a list of commits that were made on a particular branch, let's call this branch "fb-1", without the quotes.

After I view the list of commits, I want to revert back to before a particular commit.

Any suggestions? I have not done this before, so wanted to ask for advice/suggestions.

Comment: Read the docs about [git-revert - Revert some existing commits](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

Comment: this site is very helpful: https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html

Comment: Be careful: there's a difference between revert and reset. These are technical terms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Use `git log` to get a list of all commits.

You can use `git revert --no-commit a..b` to revert all the commits starting at the commit after a (note that!) and ending at, and including, commit b. The reversion will be staged for you to commit.

Comment: Okay, but I mean is this really a useful contribution to Stack Overflow? It's really no different from, say, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43081965/341994 for example. What's the point of creating a duplicate of an existing and massively popular QA?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply straight:

1. List all of the commits
   `git log`
2. Revert to specific commit
   `git revert [some id of your commit on that branch]`

You can see the details by clicking [here](https://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/How-to-git-revert-a-commit-A-simple-undo-changes-example).